# Raw Data Feed for TV Listings

Tags: data-request, media

Is there a way of grabbing a raw data feed for TV listings?

It looks like [Tribute Media](http://www.tribunemediaservices.com/tms-products-services/entertainment-data-apis/content-we-cover) offers such a thing, but at a price.

Is there any free source of open data to use out there?

Comment: Can you be specific about which geographic location(s) you're interested in? US? UK?

Comment: Quick question-how did Roku develop a live TV guide feed? Same for Pluto.tv and now YouTube guide? What technologies are they using to build it, insert the free feed and broadcasting it?

Answer (score 3):

Digital TV channels should have an [Event Information Table](http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/EIT) encoded in them, but the time window is quite limited (generally about 12 hrs).

Tribute Media used to offer free TV listings to the public, but when the popularity of MythTV and other PVRs took off, they couldn't support the amount of traffic that they were getting hit by.

As Tribue wasn't interested in dealing with lots of individuals, some folks banded together to form [SchedulesDirect](http://www.schedulesdirect.org/).  They distribute the Tribune / Zap2it data to individuals, at a moderate fee (currently $25/yr), but there are [restrictions on redistributing the data](http://www.schedulesdirect.org/sagreement).