# Structured movie/TV dataset

Tags: data-request, film

I am looking for a downloadable, always up to date and structured comprehensive dataset of movies and TV shows.

I found [this](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/589/is-there-an-open-movie-and-or-music-database-available-for-commercial-use) question and it does have some answers - DBPedia and Freebase, but they do not provide the same kind of comprehensive data+images that TheTVDB/TheMovieDB have.

Essentially what I need is a structured dataset with the data TheMovieDB/TheTVDB/IMDB have. Scraping/downloading this from an API is also an option, as long as the given service has a reasonable limit which would allow retrieving their whole dataset in a couple of days.

I would imagine there's a paid service that would sell this kind of data?

Details on what kind of information I need:

- Title, first aired/release year, certification, description, tagline
- Genres
- IMDB ID
- Cast, directors, etc.
- IMDB Rating
- TV show specific info: episodes (name, release date), seasons, runtime, status (ended/active), air date
- Posters/images
  Any additional data might be useful

Any ideas?

Comment: can you share an example (i guess url) of one of the datasets? anyone will do...i can guess, but want to make sure. i want to see i got you covered, so give me a url. please

Comment: http://thetvdb.com/data/series/79349/all/en.xml This is for a TV show. Ideally I'd get it in JSON, but it doesn't matter that much - conversion is easy.

As for a movie, http://docs.themoviedb.apiary.io/#get-%2F3%2Fmovie%2F%7Bid%7D

I am looking for a collection, as comprehensive as possible, of structured data like that. Thanks.

Comment: What information are you looking for?  The example that you have includes [schedule information](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/930/263) (when & what channel the show is on).  It also has a summary, which is copyrightable.  For movies, access to schedule data generally costs money (we used Hollywood.com when I had to do this ~15 years ago to get schedules & trailers).

Answer (score 3):

About the TV shows I know a great site ([eztv](https://eztv-proxy.net/showlist/)) with a list of airplay, info, trailers etc, but I cannot find anywhere about copywrite. Maybe you can contact with them and ask them about it.

Link: https://eztv-proxy.net/showlist/